# In Laravel::Eloquent tables, how can I set the model to read from a view, but save to a table?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

**Given:**

1. I have a MySQL table called Letter.
2. I have a string column called Letter.RecipientCode that identifies who the letter is going to.
3. The code is a string of numbers identifying the recipient's country, community, and personal ID, like so:

   0104328577
4. The first three characters of the code identify a country.
5. I have another table called Area which stores may different types of areas, one of those types is a country.
6. The Area.CountryCode field stores the match for the Letter.RecipientCode.substring(0,3).
7. The Area.Name field also stores the country name.
8. I would like to include the Area.Name in the Eloquent Letter model as a calculated field. So I wrote a simple SQL view that joins the Letter table with the Area table ON SUBSTRING(Letter.RecipientCode,1,3) = Area.CountryCode
9. I have set the Eloquent Letter model to read data from the view like so:

   protected $table = 'view_Letter';

**Problem:**

However, when I save the model using $letter->save(), it tries to insert or update back to view_Letter.

How can I read data from a view to get calculated fields, while saving data to table "Letter"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$table` for the actual table and set the view with a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#global-scopes):

```
protected $table = 'Letter';

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('from', function ($builder) {
        $builder->from('view_Letter');
    });
}
```

Comment: That's definitely an option. ... actually after looking at your suggestion, I think this might work.

Comment: This option ultimately did not work for me because it was not setting the proper 'from' table value when I instantiate a Letter model and try to use it. I'm using Laravel 5.2. Instead, I ended up overriding the Eloquent\Model save method to add the ->from('view_Letter') to the newQueryWithoutScopes() call at the top of the method. Seems rather ugly though. Wish there was a better option.